# tcolorbox vs. TikZ vs. geometry: How to put a proper grid below a tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, tcolorbox, geometry, page

On a  DINA4 (210 × 297 [mm]) paper I want to create the following:

- I need **ca. 2cm margins** to the left and the right; in the example the vertical margins becomes 2.5cm.
- I need a tcolorbox with a **total height of 6cm**.
- Below of that tcolorbox I want a grid of **2 × 2 [cm]** with **as much as possible squares in the width.**

So I choose

```
 \usepackage[    width=16cm,    height=26cm,    ]{geometry}
```

that should allow me 8 grid-squares in the width.

But why does my grid

```
% Grid:
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style=red,
remember picture,overlay,]
\draw[step=2, shift={(Textbox)}] (0,0) grid +(\linewidth-0.0*\pgflinewidth,-8);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

becomes a ***bad look at its corners***  and ***does not match correct on the tcolorbox*** (even if I choose `line cap=rect`)?  What do I have to do?

*BTW: Would it be better to create the grid as a tcolorbox too?*

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % DINA4 (210 × 297 [mm])
\usepackage[%showframe=true,
width=16cm,
height=26cm,
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
height=6cm,
sharp corners,
enhanced, remember, finish={%
\draw[blue,ultra thick,latex-] (frame.south west) coordinate[label=135:X](Textbox)-- +(3,3) node[right]{Here to put on the grid.}; }
]
A text.
\end{tcolorbox}

% Grid:
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style=red,
remember picture,overlay,]
\draw[step=2, shift={(Textbox)}] (0,0) coordinate(X) grid +(\linewidth-0.0*\pgflinewidth,-8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `width` must be equal to 17cm and not 16 cm because 21cm - 4 cm = 17 cm.

Comment: Tikz option `line cap=rect` should fix the problem.

Comment: @AndréC But with 'width=17cm' I have a problem with the 2cm squares....

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I see. That solves the problem with the bad look, but then the grid does not match correctly under the the tcolorbox.

Comment: @cis So don't ask for 2cm margins, and do it with 2.5cm margins!

Comment: @AndréC I wrote "**ca.** 2cm margins." Important are the squares

Comment: @cis I don't know what "**ca.** " means. " ! What does it mean?

Comment: ca. = circa = approximately. https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/circa

Answer (score 7):

There are differences between how the width of a `tcolorbox` environment and a `\draw grid` are determined.

- In a `tcolorbox` environment, its total natural width is exactly `\linewidth`. Here the entire left and right rules are drawn within that width.
- In a `\draw (0, 0) grid (1, 1);`, its total width is "1cm + line width", because tikz draws a line with its center right along the path.

In you situation,

- Since you need complete grids drawn, there is no room to change `\draw[..., line cap=rect] (0, 0) grid +(\linewidth, -8)`.
- Then, the `tcolorbox` environment is narrower than the grid by half of grid line width, both at left and at right sides. This is what you pointed out in [question comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553570/tcolorbox-vs-tikz-vs-geometry-how-to-put-a-proper-grid-below-a-tcolorbox?noredirect=1#comment1397533_553570).

Here is an attempt, though not elegant enough:

- Enlarge the `tcolorbox` by half the line width of grid, both at left and at right. Now `tcolorbox` has total width of "`\linewidth` + grid line width", which is the same as the following grid.
- Shift the grid horizontally by half of grid line width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % DINA4 (210 × 297 [mm])
\usepackage[%showframe=true,
  width=16cm,
  height=26cm,
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\gridlinewidth}
\setlength{\gridlinewidth}{.4pt} % default tikz line width

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  height=6cm,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=10pt,
  grow sidewards by=.5\gridlinewidth,
  enhanced,
  remember, 
  finish={%
    \draw[blue,ultra thick,latex-] 
      (frame.south west) coordinate[label=135:X] (Textbox) -- +(3,3) 
        node[right] {Here to put on the grid.}; 
  }
]
  A text.
\end{tcolorbox}

% Grid:
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every path/.style=red,
  remember picture, overlay
]
  \draw[step=2, shift={($(Textbox) + (.5\gridlinewidth, 0)$)}, line cap=rect] 
    (0, 0) grid +(\linewidth, -8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

left side
[image]

right side
[image]

Comment: Strange, I did not think that was such a big problem. Whatever, the best (and most unproblematic) result I get when I draw the grid in a new tcolorbox. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Basing on the answer of **muzimuzhi Z**, I suggest a variant with a single box which integrates drawing the grid:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % DINA4 (210 × 297 [mm])
\usepackage[%showframe=true,
  width=16cm,
  height=26cm,
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\gridlinewidth}
\setlength{\gridlinewidth}{.4pt} % default tikz line width

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,
  height=6cm,
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=10pt,
  grow sidewards by=.5\gridlinewidth,
  enlarge bottom finally by=8cm+\gridlinewidth,
  finish={%
    \begin{scope}[shift={([xshift=0.5\gridlinewidth, yshift=-0.5\gridlinewidth]frame.south west)}]
    \draw[step=2, line cap=rect, red, line width=\gridlinewidth]
        grid +(\linewidth, -8);
    \end{scope}
  }
]
  A text.
\end{tcolorbox}

Text after box and grid.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the height of the grid should be other than 8cm (4 squares), one has to adapt `enlarge bottom finally by=8cm+\gridlinewidth,` and `grid +(\linewidth, -8);` accordingly.

If your page contains nothing after box and grid, you can omit `enlarge bottom finally by=8cm+\gridlinewidth,` completely.

Comment: Seems, that the solution flys around me ears, if I set 
\setlength{\gridlinewidth}{7.4pt}        [means larger that 0.4pt].

So, I would say that the solution only works approximately, not in general. How can I fix that? I ask because the content of this tcbox is complex (more boxes ...)

Comment: @cis If you set `\gridlinewidth` to `7.4pt`, you must use `line width=7.4pt` or `line width=\gridlinewidth` in the grid drawing options, too.

Comment: Stragne, I Thought I had used that. Whatever. Very well.

Comment: I added a `line width=\gridlinewidth` to my answer to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 0):

With grid inside a new tcolorbox:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % DINA4 (210 × 297 [mm])
\usepackage[%showframe=true,
width=16cm,
height=26cm,
]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
height=6cm,
sharp corners,
after skip=0pt,
enhanced, remember, finish={%
\draw[blue,ultra thick,latex-] (frame.south west) coordinate[label=135:X](Textbox)-- +(3,3) node[right]{Here to put on the grid.}; },
]
A text.
\end{tcolorbox}

% Grid - old
%\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style=red,
%remember picture,overlay, %line cap=rect
%]
%\draw[step=2, shift={($(Textbox)+(0.5*\pgflinewidth,0)$)}] (0,0) coordinate(X) grid +(16cm-0.5*\pgflinewidth,-8);
%\end{tikzpicture}

% Grid - new
\begin{tcolorbox}[
height=8cm,
boxrule=0pt, %frame empty, 
sharp corners,
colback=white, 
before skip=0pt, after skip=0pt,
%
enhanced,
underlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
\draw[step=2, red, shift={(interior.north west)}
] (interior.south west) grid (interior.north east);
\end{tcbclipinterior}},
]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This grid is correct or better say it adjusts to previous tcolorbox, because container tcolorbox cuts the inner grid on their sides. If you look carefully, you will see that left and right grid lines are narrower than inner lines. If you want to see it more evidently, draw the grid with `line width=2mm` or any other very thick line.